# Is this theorem called Fubini's theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

In our analysis course studied a theorem (it will be stated below). After studying its analogue for triple integrals, it was noted that generelization of this theorem to multiple integrals is called Fubini's theorem. But when I found it on the Internet it was hard to me to understand how the theorem stated below is a partial case of Fubini's theorem. Is it that I don't understand something or the theorem we learnt is not a partial case of a Fubini's theorem ? In the latter case, is there any common name for the theorem we learnt ?

Theorem: $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is a compact set which can be expressed as union of sets of points between graphs of two continuous functions on some segment $[a,b]$. And $f\in C(A,\mathbb{R})$. Then the following equality holds and is properly defined:
$$\iint_{A} f(x,y) dx dy=\int_{pr_{x}A}\Big(\int_{A_x}f(x,y) dy\Big)dx$$
Where $pr_{x}A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}: \exists y\in\mathbb{R}, (x,y)\in A\}$ and $A_{x}=\{y\in\mathbb{R}:(x,y)\in A\}$

Comment: If you enclose $A$ in a bounded rectangle $X \times Y$  (for suitable intervals $X$ and $Y$) and extend $f$ by taking $f(x, y) = 0$ when $(x, y) \not\in A$., then Fubini's theorem gives you this result (as the extension makes no difference to the integral). Fubini also covers cases where $X$ and $Y$ are much complicated than intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This theorem looks like a partial case of Fubini’s theorem. To see this, first extend $f$ to a function on the whole $\mathbb R^2$ by being equal to $0$ outside $A$. Then, the left hand side of the equality above becomes

$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2} f(x,y) dx dy,$$

since $f$ is $0$ in the complement of $A$, and the right hand side becomes

$$\int_{\mathbb R}\Big(\int_{\mathbb R}f(x,y) dy\Big)dx$$

for essentially the same reason (i.e., $f(x,y)=0$ if $y\notin A_x$, and $\int_{\mathbb R}f(x,y) dy = 0$ if $x\notin pr_x A$, this last point being true because $f(x,y)=0\quad\forall y$ if $x\notin pr_x A$).

The above expressions are equal because of Fubini’s theorem. You can apply it because $f$ is bounded (it is continuous on a compact set) and has a compact support, thus it has finite integral.

Comment: Now I see that it really is a special case of Fubini's theorem. Thanks for the answer!